# Jetpack Compose building time too long when trying to add it to existing project

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I just wanted to add compose to existing project, but the build time never ended. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because of
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
. It is deprecated and somehow prevents compose from building.

Comment: Is there any documentation/evidence to validate your statement?